# Does Magento have the feature to change the color swatch on selecting a different color thumbnail?

Tags: color-swatches, thumbnail

I was checking if Magento 1.9.2 can change the color swatch on clicking over an image thumbnail of a different color.
Is this feature configurable?

Comment: What do you mean by configurable?

Comment: I wanted to know if the feature already exists in Magento, and if so should it be enabled from the backend.

Comment: Scenario:In the product detail screen there are two thumbnails with different colors, for example Blue and Black. There are two color swatches (Blue and Black). The default loaded color is Blue and on clicking the Black swatch, the Black image displays. Similarly, is there an option in Magento where I click on the Black image thumbnail which automatically selects the Black swatch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search not further, this is not a feature.
You could add a jquery onclick listener to the thumbs, filter out an attribute containing the swatch-color-id and trigger a color-swatch-click event.

That would trigger the main-image to change again also, so you'd have to come up with something to prevent the main image to switch twice after clicking the thumb.

Anyhow, you'd end up with ~10 lines of JavaScript.